# Trouble accessing methods in aws/s3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Hi I'm playing around with the aws/s3 gem so that my rails app can store and then download files from Amazon s3. I'm finding that I can't access the methods contained within the gem.

I followed the instructions in the documentation:

1. Entered into irb
2. required 'aws/s3'
3. entered interactive shell provided by aws/s3: % s3sh
4. `AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
       :access_key_id     => 'my credentials', 
       :secret_access_key => 'my credentials'
     )`

From here I believe I should be able to access my buckets and objects within them but when I call `Service.buckets` I get an error that states `undefined method 'buckets'`.

I also tried (not using s3sh):

`service = AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
        :access_key_id     => 'my credentials', 
        :secret_access_key => 'my credentials'
      )`

then `service.buckets` but still I get `undefined method 'buckets'`. How do I use this gem correctly?

Any help appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS::S3::Service.buckets listed the buckets.